# Why are "Transformers" called this way?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology, transformer, attention

What is the reason behind the name "Transformers", for Multi Head Self-Attention-based neural networks from [Attention is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762)?

I have been googling this question for a long time, and nowhere I can find any explanation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120926/discussion-on-question-by-leevo-why-are-transformers-called-this-way).

Comment: @nbro: Would you mind asking the authors why they have chosen the name "Transformer"? I am curious, too.

Answer (score 2):

The authors of the original paper don't provide an explanation, but I suspect it's a combination of:

- [popular recognizable branding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers) (cf. BERT, DALL-E, Watson etc)
- similarity to [[sequence] **trans**duction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_machine_translation) / **trans**lation / **transform**ations generally