# What makes a transformer a transformer?

Tags: deep-learning, definitions, transformer

Transformers are modified heavily in recent research. But what exactly makes a transformer a transformer? What is the core part of a transformer? Is it the *self-attention*, the *parallelism*, or something else?

Comment: When you say "Transformers are modified heavily in recent research", which research are you talking about that "modified heavily" the original transformer? In any case, [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/24643/2444) and [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/27326/2444) are 2 related questions.

Answer (score 2):

It's about *self-attention*, a mechanism that targets *parallelism* among other goals (see [1706.03762.pdf - Why Self-Attention](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf#section.4)).

From [What Is a Transformer Model? | NVIDIA Blogs](https://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2022/03/25/what-is-a-transformer-model/):

> How Transformers Got Their Name
>
> Attention is so key to transformers the Google researchers almost used the term as the name for their 2017 model. Almost.
>
> “Attention Net didn’t sound very exciting,” said Vaswani, who started working with neural nets in 2011.
>
> Jakob Uszkoreit, a senior software engineer on the team, came up with the name Transformer.
>
> “I argued we were transforming representations, but that was just playing semantics,” Vaswani said.

You'll see the same sentiment in the first paragraph of [Transformer (machine learning model)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer_(machine_learning_model)).

This is not to say that self-attention is only the kind of attention mechanism employed by a Transformer model; see [1706.03762.pdf - 3.2.3 Applications of Attention in our Model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf#subsubsection.3.2.3). It's also not to say that adding an attention mechanism to your model is to make it a "Transformer" model; the innovation of this particular model was to go "all out" on attention mechanisms (you'd also have to get rid of recurrent and convolutional components).

Answer (score 1):

There is not one answer to this question, but one could argue that transformers heavily rely on

- transforming each input into latent subspaces of queries, keys and values in order to generate attention score
- a pool of transformations of the attention vectors (multi-head) according to which models can capture richer interpretations as different sections of the input embedding can attend different per-head subspaces that link back to each input